# Update statement and cursor in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm little confused with the below update statement. For example if `@num = 1` and `ntt = 4`. While using the cursor I want to use the initial value of `num` .i.e is 1. But I'm receiving incremented value 5. What am I doing wrong ? Any help Thanks, I appreciate it.

```
UPDATE #temp
SET num = @num, 
    @num = @num + ntt

DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY DYNAMIC FOR 
    SELECT yr, id, num FROM #temp

OPEN cur
FETCH cur INTO @yr, @id, @num 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
     BEGIN
     UPDATE #TEMP2
     SET TRAN_ID = @num,
         @num = @num +1
     WHERE ...........

     FETCH cur INTO @yr, @id, @num
END
```

Comment: You set  `@num = @num + ntt` so why are you confused by `@num` = 1 + 4 = 5 ?

Comment: I"m actually migrating few stored procedures from Sybase to SQL server. The above code isn't working as expected in sql server. In sybase execution, the code is updating Tran column in Temp2 table with @num =1 which is required. But in sql server it is updating as 5. I'm confused how to make it work similar to sybase.

Answer (score 0):

The `UPDATE` does two things which you determined in the `SET`

1. Updates the num column in #temp to @num
2. Updates @num to @num + ntt

---

Comment: appreciate your response. Yes, sorry for typo, I intended to select from #temp. Exactly I'm updating the column num to 1 and incrementing @num to 5. But in cursor, I want to retrieve the num column value i.e 1 and update it in #temp2 table for column TRAN. But the value I'm receiving is 5 which is the incremented value. Any hints is really appreciated.

Comment: I guess a couple of other things before we can get to the solution. (1) If you have a column in #TEMP2 that is named `TRAN`, change it to `[TRAN]` because it's a reserved keyword (short for `TRANSACTION`).  (2) Inside your loop you are setting `@num = @num + 1` which doesn't make sense because you are `FETCH`ing the values for @num as part of the cursor

Comment: I'm using tran just as an example. In the while loop we are fetching no of records and updating it in column tran_id in #temp2. Later we are inserting in record table from #temp2.

Comment: I think you are trying to do too much with @num and maybe you need to introduce another variable to fix the problem and avoid so much confusion.  What is the point of `@num = @num +1` inside the loop?